# QTableWidget selecting multiple cells with right mouse button

Tags: python, mouseevent, qtablewidget

I have a simple QTableWidget set up like so:

```
self.table= QtGui.QTableWidget()
self.table.setEditTriggers(QtGui.QAbstractItemView.NoEditTriggers)
self.table.viewport().installEventFilter(self)
self.table.verticalHeader().setResizeMode(2)
self.table.horizontalHeader().setResizeMode(2)
```

The EventFilter reacts to:

```
def eventFilter(self, source, event):
    if event.type() == QtCore.QEvent.MouseButtonRelease:
        if event.button() == QtCore.Qt.LeftButton:
            --- LMB action ---
        if event.button() == QtCore.Qt.RightButton:
            --- RMB action ---
    return QtGui.QWidget.eventFilter(self, source, event)
```

The event works just fine for left mouse button click: it detects both a single click, and selecting multiple cells too. I would like to be able to do the same with right mouse button - right now it only recognizes a RMB click, but I can't select multiple cells. Did I mess somethin up or am I missing something?

EDIT 1:
I used `self.table.itemEntered.connect(handleItemPressed)` suggested by MarkyPython and now I have the following:

```
def eventFilter(self, source, event):

    def handleItemPressed(item):
        self.table.setItemSelected(item, 1)

    if event.type() == QtCore.QEvent.MouseButtonPress:
        if event.button() == QtCore.Qt.RightButton:
            self.table.itemEntered.connect(handleItemPressed)
    if event.type() == QtCore.QEvent.MouseButtonRelease:
        if event.button() == QtCore.Qt.LeftButton:
            --- LMB action ---
        if event.button() == QtCore.Qt.RightButton:
            --- RMB action ---
    return QtGui.QWidget.eventFilter(self, source, event)
```

Which works in a way. I am now able to select cells with both right and left mouse button, however the right mouse button selection is a little awkward (as you can imagine, it only selects the items/cells that were hovered over, unlike the classic box selection from left mouse button). So my probem is almost solved

Answer (score 1):

I have something similar in a program that I am working on right now.  You can use `itemEntered` for when you are holding down the mouse to select multiple cells and you can use `itemPressed` to select on left mouse click. The comment on line three shows what you can add if you want to select cell by cell rather than a selection. Just ask if it doesn't work.

```
self.table= QtGui.QTableWidget()
self.table.setEditTriggers(QtGui.QAbstractItemView.NoEditTriggers)
# self.table.setSelectionMode(QtGui.QAbstractItemView.NoSelection)
self.table.verticalHeader().setResizeMode(2)
self.table.horizontalHeader().setResizeMode(2)  
self.table.itemEntered.connect(self.handleItemHovered)  # handleItemHoverd is a function you create to do something when you select multiple cells
self.table.itemPressed.connect(self.handleItemPressed)  # handleItemPressed is a function you create to determine what to do when you click on the item
```

Comment: I accomodated the *itemEntered* into my code, see my edited post. Thank you for the suggestion

Comment: You should check out this [site](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt4/qtablewidget.html) for additional information about the `QTableWidget` class. It has helped me a lot.